# How to restrict to input time on edittext on the fly?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have to allow user to input only time in ##.## format in edit text on the fly, is there any way to achieve it?
I have used below code but it doesn't serve the purpose:

```
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME)
```

but this allows some alphabet also to enter as well as it will allows value like 67:344444...
I need only in 12:59(max) format , means before colon max value can be entered is 12 and after colon max can be 59..not more than that.

How to achieve it?

NOTE: I am not going to use TimePicker class because here requirement is to use Edit text and allow user to input value as Time.

Please suggest me to achieve it.

Comment: How about you restrict your EditText to 5 digits?

Comment: What about 2 EditText's declare a limit to each and combine the values in post processing. This way you insert the `:` and relieve the user of finding it in their keyboard?

Comment: may be http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `InputFilter` for control of user input:

```
    EditText editText;
    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            // here you can evaluate user input if it's correct or not
        }
    } });
```

Here is possible `filter` method implementation, but it is **not tested**:

```
            if (source.length() == 0) {
                return null;//deleting, keep original editing
            }
            String result = "";
            result.concat(dest.toString().substring(0, dstart));
            result.concat(source.toString().substring(start, end));
            result.concat(dest.toString().substring(dend, dest.length()));

            if (result.length() > 5) {
                return "";// do not allow this edit
            }
            boolean allowEdit = true;
            char c;
            if (result.length() > 0) {
                c = result.charAt(0);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '2');
            }
            if (result.length() > 1) {
                c = result.charAt(1);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
            }
            if (result.length() > 2) {
                c = result.charAt(2);
                allowEdit &= (c == ':');
            }
            if (result.length() > 3) {
                c = result.charAt(3);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '5');
            }
            if (result.length() > 4) {
                c = result.charAt(4);
                allowEdit &= (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
            }
            return allowEdit ? null : "";
```